# java get sha output in raw 20 characters binary format

Tags: java, binary, sha1

I have tried a bunch of different ways to solve this and referred to endless SO posts and most of them lead me to the hex encoded value.

Based on one of the answers on formatting the output I thought the following snippet would do the trick

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash) {
        formatter.format("%02o", b);
    }
    return formatter.toString();
```

I am trying to emulate the php sha1 function with the second parameter set to true.

Any help is much appreciated.

Add code snippets to show difference
http://ideone.com/9KNYuN

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fee17c41bd1baf688fea1ff66dbf48a3d86108c3

Comment: Just pass the byte array into a [`new String()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])).

Comment: doesnt return the same result as php does

Comment: That could be a problem with your hash function, which you haven't shown. Or it could be a character encoding issue. I'm not sure which one PHP uses.

Comment: added link to code

Comment: If you're outputting base 64, you don't need the intermediate string altogether. Just encode the byte array directly: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest("test".getBytes("UTF-8")))`

Comment: the base64 encoding was to show a tect output. what if I do not need it. I am guessing I would need to get an utf-8 encoder and do encodeToString?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're comparing it against. PHP's `sha1()` outputs raw binary as far as I understand. You would have to use *some* form of encoding to compare it to Java.

Comment: how can I output raw binary using java is my question

Comment: It's a nonsensical question. Output implies characters. Converting binary to characters requires an encoding.

Comment: srry encoding just goes way over my head.. anyways my need is to replicate the following base64Encode(sha1(string1, true)) where string is concatenation of two strings plus a sha1 encoded string. Basically trying to build a password digest. eg string1 = s1+s2+sha1(passwd,true)

Comment: So you're doing a sha1 on top of a sha1? How is the inner one encoded? Is it also base 64? Or is it a "raw" string?

Comment: its a raw string. not encoded.

Comment: Again, it is encoded, probably using PHP's [internal encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php). If that's UTF-8, for example, you should be able to replicate it in Java using `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: I have been trying that only. but no luck so far.. hence the question.. its bugging me. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fee17c41bd1baf688fea1ff66dbf48a3d86108c3 http://ideone.com/9KNYuN#view_edit_box

Comment: The PHP link is the same as before.

Comment: here you go http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9790eea98b07d3e514b81e89a031f61e80adb56

Comment: Ok, try [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba58ecb96287d8bd1c62d081c0668f41aad0de9d) and [this](http://ideone.com/qco4Qn).

Comment: http://ideone.com/koFGge  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0847f20ded47967be70f8d1cc51acf2eb5e9e3c3 doesnt work if the text is different.

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/hysvrS), you just switched the order.